# map3 in scala in Parallelism

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
def map2[A,B,C] (a: Par[A], b: Par[B]) (f: (A,B) => C) : Par[C] =
(es: ExecutorService) => {
  val af = a (es)
  val bf = b (es)
  UnitFuture (f(af.get, bf.get))
}

def map3[A,B,C,D] (pa :Par[A], pb: Par[B], pc: Par[C]) (f: (A,B,C) => D) :Par[D]  =
map2(map2(pa,pb)((a,b)=>(c:C)=>f(a,b,c)),pc)(_(_))
```

I have map2 and need to produce map3 in terms of map2. I found the solution in GitHub but it is hard to understand. Can anyone put a sight on it and explain map3 and also what this does (*(*))?

Answer (score 3):

On a purely abstract level, `map2` means you can run two tasks in parallel, and that is a new task in itself. The implementation provided for `map3` is: run in parallel (the task that consist in running in parallel the two first ones) and (the third task).

Now down to the code: first, let's give name to all the objects created (I also extended `_` notations for clarity):

```
def map3[A,B,C,D] (pa :Par[A], pb: Par[B], pc: Par[C]) (f: (A,B,C) => D) :Par[D]  = {
  def partialCurry(a: A, b: B)(c: C): D = f(a, b, c)
  val pc2d: Par[C => D] = map2(pa, pb)((a, b) => partialCurry(a, b))
  def applyFunc(func: C => D, c: C): D = func(c)
  map2(pc2d, pc)((c2d, c) => applyFunc(c2d, c)
}
```

Now remember that `map2` takes two `Par[_]`, and a function to combine the eventual values, to get a `Par[_]` of the result.

The first time you use `map2` (the inside one), you parallelize the first two tasks, and combine them into a function. Indeed, using `f`, if you have a value of type `A` and a value of type `B`, you just need a value of type `C` to build one of type `D`, so this exactly means that `partialCurry(a, b)` is a function of type `C => D` (`partialCurry` itself is of type `(A, B) => C => D`).
Now you have again two values of type `Par[_]`, so you can again `map2` on them, and there is only one natural way to combine them to get the final value.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct but I found it easier to think about like this:

```
  def map3[A, B, C, D](a: Par[A], b: Par[B], c: Par[C])(f: (A, B, C) => D): Par[D] = {
    val f1 = (a: A, b: B) => (c: C) => f(a, b, c)
    val f2: Par[C => D] = map2(a, b)(f1)
    map2(f2, c)((f3: C => D, c: C) => f3(c))
  }
```

Create a function `f1` that is a version of `f` with the first 2 arguments partially applied, then we can `map2` that with `a` and `b` to give us a function of type `C => D` in the `Par` context (`f1`).

Finally we can use `f2` and `c` as arguments to `map2` then apply `f3`(`C => D`) to `c` to give us a `D` in the `Par` context.

Hope this helps someone!